# Given a Bayesian Network, calculate $p(a)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability, bayesian-network

I am given this Bayesian Network:

[image: net]

I need to calculate $p(+d|+a)$

What I have done up to now is:

$$
p(+d|+a) := \frac{p(+d,+a)}{p(+a)}
$$
where
\begin{align}
p(+d,+a) & = \sum_X p(+d,+a,X) \\
& = p(+d) \sum_X p(+a | X, +d) p(X|+d) \\
& = 0.1 \times \big[ p(+a | +x,+d) p(+x|+d) + p(+a | -x,+d) p(-x|+d) \big] \\
& = 0.1 \times (0.9 \times 0.7 + 0.8 \times 0.3) \\
& = 0.087
\end{align}

How do I find the denominator $p(+a)$?

Is the following correct?

\begin{align}
p(+a) & = \sum_{X,D} p(+a,X,D) \\
& = \sum_{X,D} p(+a|X,D) p(X|D) p(D) \\
& = \text{...} \\
& = 0.537
\end{align}

Thus
$$
p(+d|+a) \approxeq 0.16
$$

Comment: yes the sum is correct

Comment: @0XLR Is there any technique to solve it faster?

Comment: Both numerator and denominator are correct, checked with software.

Comment: @nicola Grazie :)